# How to fix ASUS Zenbook UX305FA stuck in bios

Tags: boot, partitioning, ssd, bios, asus-laptop

I'm running Windows 8.1 on an m2 SSD. All of sudden it went to BIOS and is now stuck. I've tried BIOS defaults (no SSD shown as boot option), disabling fast boot and launching CSM, disabling secure boot, etc. I even tried reinstalled Windows, but cannot create a new partition and won't install on the one unallocated partition.

There's no recovery partition. I guess its been deleted.  Windows repair goes nowhere; I tried all options. I cannot refresh, reset or restore. The SSD shows up in the Windows installation, but not as a boot option in BIOS. I downloaded a memtest86+ ISO, but it wouldn't boot from it. I am presently using the Media Creation Tool to try to install Windows 10.

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: If your SSD doesn't show in the boot options it might be because there's nothing left on it. Which means its defective. Can you try another SSD?

Comment: Thank you yes I already ordered one and  I'm waiting for it to arrive.  I'll let you know.  Thanks again 